# angulart interface error: is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, interface

Angular says to me this error when i try tu use one interface and i dont know why.

```
file: '*******/movies.component.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Type '{ title: string; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 
'Movie'.
Property 'consructor' is missing in type '{ title: string; id: string; }'.'
at: '16,9'
source: 'ts'
```

i have this interface:

```
export class Movie{
title : string;
id : string;

consructor(title : string, id: string){
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

And i have this class

```
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
movies:Movie;
constructor(){

}
ngOnInit() {
    this.movies = {title: 'ToyStory', id:'134'};
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo  should be  `constructor(title : string, id: string)`

what syntax is this? This is wrong

```
this.movies = {title: 'ToyStory', id:'134'}
```

This is how you create an object

```
 this.movies=new Movie('ToyStory','134');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below:

in movie.model.ts:

```
export interface IMovie {
    title: string;
    id: string;
}

export class Movie implements IMovie {
    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public id: string
    ) { }
}
```

in movie.component.ts:

```
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
    private _movies: Movie[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this._movies.push(new Movie('ToyStory','134'));
    }
}
```

Why are you using a string for id?